# Unable to read the token id from json response code using regular expression extractor in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have to do performance testing for ipad application.
There is scenario in which i have to read the token id from the response and use this token id in my next request.
I used the regular expression extractor, but when i used the variable in next request i.e. ${tokenid}, it wasn't replaced with the captured value. When i look at View Result tree, it is simply requesting the variable instead of token.
Here is the regular expression extractor

Comment: I didn't working out for me. Here is request which is hitting to server. POST data:
{"Token":"${tokenid}"}
The "tokenid" is not replacing by the actual value

Comment: Please show the test plan screenshot, at least previous sampler and children and the one with var, also show response that contains token

Answer (score 0):

There is at least an error where you must check:

- Body

instead of checking :

- Response Code

in Regular Expression Extractor

You can use View Result to check your regexp:

[image]

Finally regexp should be:

```
"Token":"([^"]+?)"
```

Comment: I tried selecting the 'Body', even other options also. but it didn't work. Is there any way to verify that regular expression extractor is reading the Token or not. This is my token id:
{"Token":"e4378e76-3085-4ef3-a223-7b8a30283a0e"}

Comment: Your problem is that you checked "Respoonse Code" in Regular Expression Extractor , you must check Body .